# Cloudwatch deleting alarms with INSUFFICIENT_DATA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have numerous alarms related to Dynamodb autoscaling that show INSUFFICIENT_DATA. All together they're adding to my AWS costs.

Is it okay for me to delete them?

How do I have them deleted automatically?

Comment: One presumes that you created these alarms, and would delete them the same way. How did you create them? Why did you create them? Add that to your question and it may become answerable.

Comment: They were created automatically by dynamodb autoscaling. It goes without saying that if I'd created them I'd be comfortable deleting them.

Comment: Do you want auto-scaling?  The alarms are what triggers it to scale, aren't they?

Comment: They are but do the one's with insufficient_data count? I have a few hundred of those

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my environment, where I had close to 600 alarms with the INSUFFICIENT_DATA state. I was sure that I was not using/needing any of them so I just ran this script and deleted them all.

```js
//Delete CloudWatch Alarms by INSUFFICIENT_DATA

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1'
})
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

const params = {
    StateValue: "INSUFFICIENT_DATA"
}

// Get Alarm Names with INSUFFICIENT_DATA state
cloudwatch.describeAlarms(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else {
        // delete alarms
        const alarmNames = data.MetricAlarms.map(alarm => alarm.AlarmName);
        const parmasDelete = {
            AlarmNames: alarmNames
        }
        cloudwatch.deleteAlarms(parmasDelete, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);  
        })
    }
});
```

This only deletes 50 alarms per run, but if you need to increase that limit, there's a way to do this, just check the aws-sdk

Just save the above code on a file and run the command: node filename.js

filename.js - is the name of the file you saved the script

NOTE: you need to have aws-sdk installed on the same folder where you save this script, you can install that with this command: npm install aws-sdk

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The INSUFFICIENT_DATA message is merely a result of the cloudwatch log not being active for the measured time period or no logs being received. For example, if the log is looking at a 1 minute period and no logs have been submitted, you will get this message.

Any charges related to these logs are just charges for the logging service. If you wish to avoid those, you'll need to disable cloudwatch logs on your DynamoDB.

Please reference this AWS user guide for more details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: Alarms are ~$0.10/per month beyond the free tier, each.